# scipy block_diag does not preserve complex numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, scipy, block

I wrote a function that puts tensor products of Pauli matrices on the diagonal, using the block_diag function.

When I implement the function , I obtain:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1]])
```

as you can see, the matrix

```
array([[ 0 , -1j],[1j,0]])
```

is missing, being replaced by a 2x2 0 matrix.

The warning it gives me is :

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/special_matrices.py:541: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
out[r:r + rr, c:c + cc] = arrs[i]
```

Any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: can you add a snippet of the code that generated this output?

Comment: It mostly uses other functions, but this is the function itself 'code' ( def Gmatrix(n):
    lst = list(qg.pauli_basis(n))
    matrix_list = [0]*len(lst)
    
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        matrix_list[i] = qg.P(lst[i])
    
    Gmat = block_diag(*matrix_list)
    return Gmat )

Comment: SOLVED: just add "dtype = np.complex128" when defining your complex matrix, otherwise it thinks it's real.